# Translate a Web Service POST from Java to .NET

Tags: java, visual-studio, http-post, httpclient

Below is a snipped from a Java Client that connects to a website and uploads a file via the POST method.  I have to reproduce this client in a Visual Studio environment, but I don't see any equivalent functions in the .NET environment for the [setEntity()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase.html#setEntity%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) function used in the Java.

Everything I've found points to using this...

```
public void uploadFile(File uploadFile, String partner, String key,
            String baseUrl,boolean isPartner) throws IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
        CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1
    );
    String url = baseUrl + "?" + (isPartner ? "partnerId" : "ori") + "="
            + partner.toUpperCase() + "&authKey=" 
            + key+ "&key=" 
            + key;
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    ContentBody contentBody = new FileBody(uploadFile, "text/xml"); 
    multipartEntity.addPart("dataFile", contentBody); 
    httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    if (resEntity != null) {
        resEntity.consumeContent();
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Everything I've found in Visual studio uses something like this below for the POST method.  The [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) object has no obvious way of adding the parameters I need.

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://Test.com/import?partnerId=2&authKey=XdUa")
request.Method = "POST"
Dim postData As String = StrData
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
request.ContentType = "dataStr"
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream.Close()
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  If my question is not clear, let me know, I'll try again.

Comment: Your code looks like Visual Basic to me. I don't know that language, but if it is, your tags should also reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code snippet to add the parameter

request.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Dim postData As String = "name1="+value1+"&name2="+value2

Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

Rest will remain same.